# error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

Can't figure out what is wrong with my SQL statement full error message is

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL , 
    `Sex` BOOLEAN NOT NULL , 
    PRIMARY KEY(userID)
    )' at line 7
```

actual code is

```
CREATE TABLE `car_rental`.`users` ( 
`userID` int(9) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL ,
`First Name` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL , 
`Last Name` VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL ,
`E-mail Address` VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL , 
`Age` INT NOT NULL , 
`Password` VARCHAR NOT NULL , 
`Sex` BOOLEAN NOT NULL , 
PRIMARY KEY(userID)
) 
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: No length on the varchar on the password field I noticed.

Comment: thanks for that @Andrew pretty new to SQL it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is mainly because:

```
`Password` VARCHAR NOT NULL
```

Change it to:

```
`Password` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
```

Hope this helps.